# Symfony createNativeQuery, add count()

Tags: php, sql, symfony

I have a query in a repository like :

```
    $rsm = new ResultSetMapping;
    $rsm->addEntityResult('\My\ProjectBundle\Entity\News', 't');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('t', 'id', 'id');
    $rsm->addMetaResult('t', 'account_id', 'account_id');
$qb = $this->_em->createNativeQuery(
                'SELECT t.*
                    FROM news as t
                    LEFT JOIN 
                        LEFT JOIN
                    WHERE
                        CONDITIONS CONDITIONS

                    ',
                $rsm
            );
            return $qb->getResult();
```

I simplified the above query which is used to retrieve the news that meet specific conditions.

I need to add a `count()` function to this query.

I have an other `ManyToOne` entity-relationship between `Comment` and `News`.

How to modify the query to get the comments number a given news has ?

I'm trying to add a left join to comment and add  `Count()` in the select but I always  get errors. How could I resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Raw SQL with **Doctrine** is easier like this :

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getConnection();

$query = "
 SELECT t.*
 FROM news as t
 LEFT JOIN 
    LEFT JOIN
 WHERE
    CONDITIONS CONDITIONS
"; 
$stmt = $em->prepare($query); 
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```